# Why does paxtest show OpenBSD as vulnerable?

Tags: openbsd

```
install60.iso
Executable anonymous mapping (mprotect) : Vulnerable
Executable bss (mprotect) : Vulnerable
Executable data (mprotect) : Vulnerable
Executable heap (mprotect) : Vulnerable
Executable shared library bss (mprotect) : Vulnerable
Executable shared library data (mprotect) : Vulnerable
Return to function (strcpy) : paxtest : return address contains a NULL byte.
Return to function (strcpy, PIE) : paxtest : return address contains a NULL byte.
Return to function (memcpy) : Vulnerable
Return to function (memcpy, PIE) : Vulnerable
```

Paxtest outputs on a few OS:

https://s22.postimg.org/f169vbabl/paxtest_openbsd.png

https://lut.im/C3F0KIhF6O/GPjZ5bRQrTK8fLpg.png

**Question**: Why is OpenBSD vulnerable? How can we harden it?

Increasing kern.stackgap_random=262144 to kern.stackgap_random=16777216 increases the "14 quality bits" to "20 quality bits".

But couldn't figure out how to fix the other Vulnerable parts.

Or the question should go to the security.stackexchange?

**UPDATE**: after: @Rufo El Magufo

wxallowed was in only at /usr/local, removed it:

```
# grep wxallowed /etc/fstab
# grep wxallowed /etc/fstab-BACKUP                                                                                                                           
2acbf0d2ff8159d4.h /usr/local ffs rw,wxallowed,nodev 1 2
#
```

and set the sysctl (but imho isn't this just for debugging purposes?)

```
# sysctl kern.wxabort
kern.wxabort=1
# grep kern.wxabort /etc/sysctl.conf
kern.wxabort=1
#
```

and rebooted, then ran the paxtest:

```
# ./paxtest blackhat                                                                                                                                         
PaXtest - Copyright(c) 2003-2016 by Peter Busser <peter@adamantix.org> and Brad Spengler <spender@grsecurity.net>
Released under the GNU Public Licence version 2 or later

Writing output to /root/paxtest.log
It may take a while for the tests to complete
Test results:
gcc: no input files

Executable anonymous mapping             : Killed
Executable bss                           : Killed
Executable data                          : Killed
Executable heap                          : Killed
Executable stack                         : Killed
Executable anonymous mapping (mprotect)  : Vulnerable
Executable bss (mprotect)                : Vulnerable
Executable data (mprotect)               : Vulnerable
Executable heap (mprotect)               : Vulnerable
Executable shared library bss (mprotect) : Vulnerable
Executable shared library data (mprotect): Vulnerable
Executable stack (mprotect)              : Killed
Anonymous mapping randomization test     : 33 quality bits (guessed)
Heap randomization test (ET_EXEC)        : 38 quality bits (guessed)
Main executable randomization (ET_EXEC)  : 25 quality bits (guessed)
Shared library randomization test        : 33 quality bits (guessed)
Stack randomization test (SEGMEXEC)      : 20 quality bits (guessed)
Stack randomization test (PAGEEXEC)      : 20 quality bits (guessed)
Arg/env randomization test (SEGMEXEC)    : 20 quality bits (guessed)
Arg/env randomization test (PAGEEXEC)    : 20 quality bits (guessed)
Return to function (strcpy)              : paxtest: return address contains a NULL byte.
Return to function (strcpy, PIE)         : paxtest: return address contains a NULL byte.
Return to function (memcpy)              : Vulnerable
Return to function (memcpy, PIE)         : Vulnerable
Executable shared library bss            : Killed
Executable shared library data           : Killed
Writable text segments                   : Killed

# pwd
/root/paxtest-0.9.15-bsdfix
# 
# uname -mrs
OpenBSD 6.0 amd64
#
```

still says "Vulnerable", strange.

Comment: but I still doesn't understand why are they shown as vulnerable: http://blog.acumensecurity.net/revisiting-wx-with-openbsd-6-0

Comment: can someone please redirect from unix.stackexchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if anyone interested, correction for the pax topic
>
> Sent: Tuesday, October 11, 2016 at 3:57 PM From: "W. Dean Freeman"
>    To: "'Peter Janos'"
>    Subject: RE: RE: OpenBSD PaX Test question
>   Increasing the stack gap size isn't necessarily bad or good.
>   Basically, you're adjusting the run-time value of a gap page that gets
>   inserted at the top of a new stack frame, so that when an attacker is
>   analyzing a binary and attempting to write an exploit, there is an
>   unknown-at-compile-time number of bytes which have to be included when
>   building the exploit and attempting to over-write the return address
>   to the previous stack frame. It's just one of a series of mitigations
>   against buffer overflows (like stack canaries, W^X, etc. You're also
>   here adjusting the amount of room there is to play with when
>   randomzing addresses for ASLR, at least as is my understanding.
>
> So, I doubt it hurts anything, but given the general strength of ASLR,
>   stack gaps, stack cookies, the new W^X feature, etc. I'm not sure it's
>   really necessary. If you really want to play with something fun that
>   may ferret out bugs either in your code or in things you get from
>   ports, turn on memory junking in the /etc/malloc.conf. For a
>   discussion on some fun around that, see here:
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYf1U0xcHmk
>
> To the second question, there isn't any magic to what I'm doing in
>   that program and between screenshots from GDB and a description of
>   what's going on, you should be able to reconstruct it. There are three
>   basic tests:
>   1. Attempt to mmap(2) a page of memory with permissions PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC
>   ** on OpenBSD, this will cause the program to abort. On HardenedBSD or NetBSD, you'll get a writable page of memory back
>   ** If you get the page back, I put a bit of do-nothing shell code into the mapped buffer, then write a function pointer to it and attempt to
>   execute in order to cause a page fault there and record the violation
>   is caught properly, proving that I didn't get W|X memory
>   2. attempt to map a page of memory as writable then mprotect() to W|X. With PaX, the page stays writable. OpenBSD will abort the processes
>   here
>   ** I did share a version with Red Hat through technical community channels, which included proof via live shell code that even if you
>   turn off execmem allocation in SELinux, that you get no protection
>   around mprotect and can still get a shell here.
>   3. Attempt to map a page of memory as executable and then mprotect() to W|X. Again, OpenBSD will abort this but PaX just gives you back
>   what you had originally
>
> I may be able to share the tool, but it basically just does a subset
>   of what is in the paxtest, geared directly at three sub-cases for one
>   security functional requirement which isn't even mandatory right now.
>   However, RedHat didn't want to burn political capital with the Linux
>   kernel devs pushing for it when OpenBSD didn't even turn it on. Now
>   that they have, there may be a better case to be made in that regard.
>
> ----- W. Dean Freeman, CISSP, CSSLP, GCIH Lead Security Engineer Mobile: +1.8048158786 wdfreeman@acumensecurity.net
>   http://www.acumensecurity.net
>
> -----Original Message----- From: Peter Janos [mailto:peterjanos2@mail.com] Sent: Tuesday, October 11, 2016 2:23 AM
>   To: W. Dean Freeman  Subject: Re: RE:
>   OpenBSD PaX Test question
>
> Only two question:
>
> ======================================
>
> 1) Increasing kern.stackgap_random=262144 to
>   kern.stackgap_random=16777216 increases the "14 quality bits" to "20
>   quality bits".
>
> Stack randomization test (SEGMEXEC) : 20 quality bits (guessed) Stack
>   randomization test (PAGEEXEC) : 20 quality bits (guessed) Arg/env
>   randomization test (SEGMEXEC) : 20 quality bits (guessed) Arg/env
>   randomization test (PAGEEXEC) : 20 quality bits (guessed
>
> is this a wise thing to do? Does setting the kern.stackgap_random to
>   16777216 increases security?
>
> ======================================
>
> 2) Can we have the cc-memtest binary or source? Or it is not public.
>   http://blog.acumensecurity.net/revisiting-wx-with-openbsd-6-0/
>
> ======================================
>
> Many Thanks!
>
> > Sent: Monday, October 10, 2016 at 5:46 PM
> >     From: "W. Dean Freeman" 
> >     To: "'Peter Janos'" 
> >     Subject: RE: OpenBSD PaX Test question
> >
> > Sure, go ahead.
> >
> > From: Peter Janos [mailto:peterjanos2@mail.com]
> >     Sent: Monday, October 10, 2016 11:46 AM
> >     To: W. Dean Freeman 
> >     Subject: Re: OpenBSD PaX Test question
> >
> > can I post this as an anser on stackexchange?
> >
> > Thank you!
> >
> > Sent: Monday, October 10, 2016 at 4:36 PM
> >     From: "W. Dean Freeman"  >
> >     To: peterjanos2@mail.com 
> >     Subject: OpenBSD PaX Test question
> >
> > -----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
> >     Hash: SHA1
> >
> > Hi Peter,
> >
> > I'm the author of the blog post that you referenced in your stack exch
> >     ange post.
> >
> > As you may note from the blog post, I make three points in particular:
> >
> > 1. OpenBSD does not follow the PaX model (and therefor shouldn't be
> >        expected to do everything that paxtest checks for, necessarily, and
> >        certainly not in the same way) 2. In OpenBSD, you can still use
> >        mprotect() To switch between wri table and executable pages of memory,
> >        because what is enforced is stri ctly W^X, not W!->X.
> > 2. My claims about OpenBSD 6.0 were strictly in relation to the c
> >        onformance with FPT_W^X_EXT.1 in the latest revisions of the NIAP-appr
> >        oved Operating System Protection Profile for Common Criteria.
> >
> > So, an operating system like HardenedBSD or NetBSD, which follow the P
> >     aX model, will not allow you to successfully do something like this:
> >     * Map a page of memory as writable
> >     * Subsequently mprotect() that page to W|X
> >     * OR mprotect() that page to just X after it was W
> >
> > On OpenBSD, the behavior is:
> >     * You cannot map a page of memory W|X
> >     * You cannot mprotect(2) a page of memory that is W to W|X
> >     * You can map a page of memory as, say, R|W, then mprotect(2) t o R|X
> >
> > This allows you to, say, run new Firefox builds, which use this mprote
> >     ct(2) swapping method to keep pages allocated by the JIT from being W|
> >     X at the same time without having to push Firefox off onto a separate
> >     /opt filesystem or something where you have fs flags to remove the W^X
> >     protections. In HardenedBSD or NetBSD you would still have to use se
> >     cadm or paxctl to remove the mprotect hardening on a per-binary/per-pr
> >     ocess basis because the PaX model wouldn't let you swap the permission
> >     s.
> >
> > I demonstrated this in the blog post, towards the end, and then explai
> >     ned why this matters in the context of JITs.
> >
> > Please let me know if you have any other questions, but I hope this he
> >     lps clear it up. Essentially, your'e going to get those "vulnerable"
> >     messages from the pax test tool because OpenSBD doesn't do PaX.
> >
> > Thanks,
> >     Dean
> >
> > ---
> >
> > W. Dean Freeman, CISSP, CSSLP, GCIH
> >     Lead Security Engineer
> >     Mobile: +1.8048158786
> >     wdfreeman@acumensecurity.net 
> >     
> >     http://www.acumensecurity.net http://www.acumensecurity.net/
> >
> > -----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
> >
> > iQFRBAEBAgA7BQJX+6daNBxXaWxsaWFtIERlYW4gRnJlZW1hbiA8d2RmcmVlbWFu
> >     QGFjdW1lbnNlY3VyaXR5Lm5ldD4ACgkQrnqwKenh3fRbrQgAjFsvyXA6bZIPYyjX
> >     0A3ldKlFTekRuyFnhmWuX3CsK5eV7azrADyamuPV5T2YMN7U0tmjcOC9hOX3OPsK
> >     0IC9YqTjGxpLuxt0Z7GeXeeRO58SvroKMbsKZz6pU8pvKAJn8Hl/0UcAJsmfcHUd
> >     6ErH7wuHgpCEzTHGkiEIz1W/kPZXUsRhT9XpURUCBwOp01vsl5Lm9GfYWb64zHCM
> >     f9fDwkasE/Dy8amn907bGLSP1M711HhVB5cP76xe0twYyxOKtNRlJno2Kc9cEr4D
> >     d2U/r/iCG8A9Qabp+QBuxVWTdP3kq2LwDqb6ySUSLLrSYLbRjUOi+7GhQer3yM+r
> >     6TEFcQ==
> >     =gBZh
> >     -----END PGP SIGNATURE-----